# Ruby Net::Ftp storbinary with non ascii filename

Tags: ruby

I do not succeed to store my file with a filename that contain non ascii char.

I use `storbinary("STOR #{remotefile}", data, 512, &block)`,
with this filename `Filename_Mémo.pdf` but the result on the FTP is `Filename_MÃ©mo.pdf`

Any Idea ?
Thanks.

Comment: That's the result of (mis)interpreting UTF-8 as ISO 8859-1 (or vice-versa, depending on your point of view).

Comment: Can you be more specific about what "the result on the FTP" means? After you store the file, how are you viewing its name and seeing the wrong characters? Can you be sure the problem is in the storing and not the viewing?

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, solved with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644103/ruby-converting-string-encoding-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8-not-working