# Parsing UTF-8 with Faraday

Tags: ruby, character-encoding, faraday

I'm making an API request with Faraday in Ruby and I'm parsing it with `JSON.parse`. The problem is that, the JSON response has sentences such as `Longitud de la estaci\u00F3n meteorol\u00F3gica (grados)` but it should be `Longitud de la estación meteorológica (grados)`.

Is there a way to properly parse this? 
I have `connection = Faraday.new(my_site)` and if I do `connection.get.body.encoding`, then I get `#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>`, but when I try `connection.get.body.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT).force_encoding('UTF-8)` or `connection.get.body.force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT).encode('UTF-8)` I get `'encode': "\xF3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)`.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you post String#bytes of the relevant substring, like "estación" part, in the JSON string? I can't tell "\u00F3" is an ASCII string of 6 bytes or a one-byte 8-bit string...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
connection.get.body.force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
```

I don't know about Faraday, but judging from `Encoding::UndefinedConversionError` error, that is perhaps the case.  I am assuming `connection.get.body` returns a normal String instance or its equivalent.

### Background

As the [official document (Ver.2.5.1)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Encoding.html) states, you should not try to convert `ASCII-8BIT` to any other encodings:

> Encoding::ASCII_8BIT is a special encoding that is usually used for a byte string, not a character string.

The so-called extended ASCII, which contains some punctuations for alphabet, is usually ISO-8859-1, though other encoding methods exist.  Certainly the codepoint of `o` with `'` is \xF3 in ISO-8859-1.  Here is a code snippet to demonstrate it:

```
"\xf3".force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
  # => "ó"
"\xf3".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT').encode('UTF-8')
  # => Encoding::UndefinedConversionError
```

[This past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644103/ruby-converting-string-encoding-from-iso-8859-1-to-utf-8-not-working) explains it in a bit more detail.